# How to change alternating table indent in LibreOffice Impress?

Tags: libreoffice-impress

I'm creating a bunch of tables in a LibreOffice Impress document. I like the built-in Table Design styles, including the Banded Rows, but I want to remove the indentation on alternate rows. I've tried every setting in Paragraph, Style, etc.

What I'm trying to achieve:

[image: Example of what I want]

How do I remove the indent on Row 2 and Row 4?

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the cell, click "table," click "borders," see "spacing to contents," set each to 0.01.